# Multinomial regression after PCA

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, pca, multinomial-distribution

I have extracted 7 factors from 25 variables using principal component analysis with varimax rotation. Now I want to use these factors as independent variables and study their relation with an ordinal dependent variable. For this I applied multinomial logistic regression in SPSS. But it gives me a warning that a number of cells have zero frequencies. What should be done?

Comment: Ordinal or multinomial regression? You say your DV is ordinal.

Comment: It's worth noting that, if you used PCA, you *do not* have "factors", you have *principal components*.

Comment: multinomial regression.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. 
Before trying the multinomial model you should build all possible crosstabs to identify zero frequencies cells. Nonetheless, it is possible that during the modelling process, zero frequencies can appear because of the "combinations".
You may try to merge some categories or to identify those independent variables with "insufficient" $N$. 
Apparently the problem with zero frequencies is that you can no longer assume a $\chi^2$ distribution for your data and then it will be difficult to interpret whether or not the goodness-of-fit test is reliable. 
I have no idea if a "tolerable" zero frequencies exists. Actually, I came to this post looking for an answer to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gung states, you need to modify the PCA definition since you are dealing with ordinal (categorical) outputs. In the naive case you do not have "factors" but principal components.

One solution to the problem is to consider normal prior in the latent space and a logic likelihood. To be more precise

$P(z) = N(z|0,I)$

$P(V|z) = Cat(V|S^{T}z)$

(In the naive probabilistic factor analysis/pca, the second step would look something like $P(V|Z) = N( Az+b, \Psi)$

In the above expression, cat is a model used to fit categorical data (typically logistic regression). The above model can be fit using EM